# How to name application specific fields in couchdb

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I tried adding my own fields with names like `_myappvar` and `_myotherappvar` to documents to distinguish them from data fields. At first it worked but at some point futon starts to complain.

What is the right way to go?

I am using couchdb 0.9.0, this may be old, butI will not be able to upgrade in this iteration.

*Edit:* I guess `_*` is reserved for couchdb vars. I could choose something else but is there a best practice or ho are you solving this?

*Edit2:* This is somehow severe for my application, because it is already live with those fields. I wonder under which circumstances I can keep the parts that work and only apply a new naming for future fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The [CouchDB Document API, Special Fields](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Special_Fields) section explains it.

**Top-level fields may not begin with `_`.**

*CouchDB is relaxed*, so the best way to go is the easiest thing for your application. About your specific edits:

1. One idea is to use the `_` *suffix* instead of a prefix. Another idea is a `.myapp` field which is an object(namespace) for your internal data. You could combine them too:

   ```
   {
     "type": "the document type",
     "var1": "Normal variable 1",
     "var2": true,
     "myapp_": {
       "var": "Something internal",
       "othervar": null,
     }
   }
   ```

   Now you can reference `doc.myapp_.var` in your view maps, reduces, etc.
2. You have a choice. You can bite the bullet and change all documents right now. I don't know your app however I prefer that because you are playing with fire using a `_` prefix.

   However, you could also have both types of document and simply teach your `map()` function how to handle both of them.

   ```
   function(doc) {
     if(doc.type == "the document type") {
       if(doc._myappvar) {
         emit(doc._id, doc._myappvar); // The old way
       } else if(doc.myapp_) {
         emit(doc._id, doc.myapp_.var); // The new way
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Good luck!